# Dapper with Oracle give ORA-00936: missing expression error

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions, dapper-simplecrud

I am using Dapper, with Dapper.Extensions and Dapper.SimpleCRUD.  The following code works fine when running against a MYSQL database.  However when I run the same code with the same tables against oracle I get ORA-00936: missing expression error.  I am not sure why I am getting this error because I am simply trying to retrieve all records from the table.

```
//MYSQL DDL
CREATE TABLE app_config(
    `app_config_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
    `user_name` nvarchar(100) NULL,     
    `program_location` nvarchar(400) NULL,      
    CONSTRAINT PK_tk_app_config_id PRIMARY KEY (app_config_id)    );  

//ORACLE DDL
CREATE TABLE app_config(
    app_config_id number(10)  NOT NULL,
    user_name nvarchar2(100) NULL,      
    program_location nvarchar2(400) NULL,       
    CONSTRAINT PK_tk_app_config_id PRIMARY KEY (app_config_id));

CREATE SEQUENCE app_config_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER app_config_seq_tr
 BEFORE INSERT ON app_config FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (NEW.app_config_id IS NULL)
BEGIN
 SELECT app_config_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.app_config_id FROM DUAL;
END;
/

//C# Code    
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Dapper;

namespace RetrieveAll
{
    public class app_config
        {
            [Key]
            public int app_config_id { get; set; }
            public string user_name { get; set; }
            public string program_location { get; set; }


        }

 public static IDbConnection getDBConnection(string dbtype)
        {
            switch (dbtype)
            {
                default:                
                case "MYSQL":
                    return new MySqlConnection("userid=uid;password=pwd;server=localhost;database=test");
                case "ORACLE":
                    return new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=tempdb)));User ID=uid;Password=pwd;");


            }
        }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              using (var connection = dbConnector.getDBConnection("ORACLE"))
            {

              var ac = connection.GetList<app_config>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see anywhere in your code you instruct your ORM which RDBMS you are using.

The root cause of the error is explained [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00936.php):

> Cause
> You tried to execute a SQL statement but you omitted a part of the syntax.

This might be caused because ORM is generating incorrect query. This may happen because you did not set the `Dialect` properly. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53019287/5779732) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61183992/5779732) for more details.

With Dapper Extensions, you need to set `SqlDialect` as below:

```
//Synchronous
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = 
    new DapperExtensions.Sql.MySqlDialect();//or OracleDialect

//Asynchronous
DapperExtensions.DapperAsyncExtensions.SqlDialect = 
    new DapperExtensions.Sql.MySqlDialect();//or OracleDialect
```

Similarly, for Simple CRUD, you set the [`Dialect`](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD#database-support) as below:

```
   SimpleCRUD.SetDialect(SimpleCRUD.Dialect.PostgreSQL);
    
   SimpleCRUD.SetDialect(SimpleCRUD.Dialect.MySQL);
```

This tells the ORM which RDBMS you are using. It generates the query accordingly.

I never used SimpleCRUD, but looking at supported dialects for it, Oracle is not supported:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Database server dialects
public enum Dialect
{
    SQLServer = 0,
    PostgreSQL = 1,
    SQLite = 2,
    MySQL = 3
}
```

There is separate repository on GitHub named [Dapper.SimpleCRUD-with-Oracle-](https://github.com/jmo21/Dapper.SimpleCRUD-with-Oracle-). You may need to use it for Oracle.

Comment: I did not find the Dapper.SimpleCrud-with-Oracle- in NuGet.  Do I have to add the source code from github to my project for it to work?

Comment: @WestonGoodwin: Not sure, I never used it. But you can always add source code anyway. By the way, why you are using two ORMs (Dapper Extensions and SimpleCRUD) those serve same purpose? I think you can avoid SimpleCRUD and only use Dapper Extensions. For any complex scenario, fall back to Dapper.

Comment: I was confused as to what I should use so I used them all.  I will use plain Dapper going forward.  Thank you for your help.