# Dapper exact query being sent to database engine

Tags: .net, sql-server, dapper

Looking for a way to get the exact query which is sent to SQL Server after substituting literals / parameters.

Executed code:

```
result = connection.Query(Of MyList)(query, New With {Key .A = A, Key .B = B, Key .C = C})
```

I would like to capture (in the code, not at the database server side) exact query where parameters @A, @B and @C are already substituted with its values.

Comment: You can log the query as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875558/5779732). It is for Dapper Extensions; but same is applicable for Dapper without change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper doesn't provide such a capability. You will have to fork its source code and add this sort of logging yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> where parameters @A, @B and @C are already substituted with its values.

Parameters aren't substituted.  The query with the parameter markers is the exact query sent to the server.  The parameter values are sent separately.